# add clickable/hyperlink text to datagrid text during runtime

Tags: wpf

I am want to add clickable/hyperlink text to datagrid text during runtime.

Here is my XAML code for DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid Height="298" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,273,0,0" Name="ResultDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="415" 
 RowBackground="#6B8DBBD1" AlternatingRowBackground="#CAD3D3BB" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
 CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#97000000" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#97000000" />
```

On a Button click, I am adding ItemSource to DataGrid

```
    var resultDT = CDataBaseHelper.GetProjectsReviewedBtw(sDate, eDate);
        if(resultDT !=null)
        {
            ResultDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            ResultDataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadCollectionData(resultDT);
            ResultDataGrid.Focus();

            NoofRecordFoundLable.Content = resultDT.Rows.Count + " records found";
        }
```

Here is my LoadCollectionData, which will return collection

```
    private List<ReviewedData> LoadCollectionData(DataTable resultData)
    {
        List<ReviewedData> result = new List<ReviewedData>();

        if (resultData != null && resultData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < resultData.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                result.Add( new ReviewedData()
                {
                    PROJECTNAME = resultData.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString(),
                    STATUS = resultData.Rows[i]["status"].ToString()
                });                    
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

How I can add clickable/hyperlink text to each PROJECTNAME, so that I can open new window to show more project details on each project displayed in DataGrid?

Any suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying UI at runtime, you should rely more on databinding and templating. That's the nature of WPF.

For this case, you may want to consider using `DataGridHyperlinkColumn`. Don't forget to turn off `AutoGenerateColumns` feature since you want to control appearance of the column :

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         .... >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding PROJECTNAME}" Header="Name">
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="Hyperlink_Click"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding STATUS}" Header="Status"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then you can handle hyperlink clicked event according to your needs :

```
private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink)e.OriginalSource;
    //Do something useful instead of just showing the hyperlink text in message box :
    MessageBox.Show(link.NavigateUri.ToString());
}
```